# How do I get unity back after installing nVidia drivers

Tags: unity, nvidia, dell, intel, .desktop

I know this might look like a repeated question
but I've been looking for a solution everywhere I could think of with no success

I am using a Dell Inspiron N5110
It has intel shared graphics and an nVidia GeForce GT 525M graphics card
Running Ubuntu 13.04 64-Bit

Which is very bad for some reason

anyways,
I installed drivers for the nVidia card from the Xorg Edgers
Huge mistake
because now, unity won't appear
I can only see my desktop and the files on it
which sucks because I can't really run any programs
The only reason I'm able to use Chrome to write this is because I have an html page on the desktop
I open it, then it opens in chrome
other than that, the launcher and top bar are gone
I can only close chrome by closing all tabs
and have to shutdown from terminal

I installed bumblebee, nvidia drivers
removed them
reinstalled them again
NOTHING CHANGED

I AM STILL UNABLE TO USE UNITY

I know someone somewhere has a solution other than reinstalling ubuntu
Can you please help me internet?

**UPDATE:**
I have used the following commands
    `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/`
    `unity --reset-icons &disown`
to get unity to reappear
the launcher doesn't have my old icons, it has the default ones
and when I run it through the terminal, it produces a  giant list of errors
I don't want to have to run this every time I start Ubuntu!!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the `unity --reset` does not work any longer as it has been deprecated.

I have found this project in Github that may be a solution to your problem: https://github.com/phanimahesh/unity-revamp

Download the file `unity-reset.py` to a folder then execute it in a terminal with the following command `python unity-reset.py`.

Give it a try.

Comment: $ python unity-reset.py 
  File "unity-reset.py", line 4
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove all those ppa with the ppa-purge to clear all the packages they installed.

`sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`

and then

`sudo ppa-purge ppa:example`

Reboot and install again the Nvidia drivers that Ubuntu additional drivers list. Staying with the drivers Ubuntu offer is the best solution.

Comment: Before, nothing appeared in the additional drivers tab..
I can't look in it now because I can't figure out how to access it..
will try and post results

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to install and launch the compiz config setting manager (ccsm):

   `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
   `sudo ccsm`
2. check **OpenGL**
3. click on **Ubuntu Unity Plugin**
4. check **activate Unity plugin** in the left margin
   you'll then be requested to activate other plugins and resolve some keyboard shortcuts

Et voilà, the unity menu bar and launch bar will appear.

*Note* : you should select to use NVIDIA drivers by using the **control pannel** -> **Software and update** -> **additional drivers**. I selected the top most radio button. (I'm translating from french, so the names may not be exactly the one you see.)

Comment: That's the weird part, it never appeared in there  
there was nothing in the additional drivers tab before
and I can't access it now  

also, I tried this and it didn't work

Comment: There still is nothing in the additional drivers tab, I removed the ppa's that I added.. but it still won't show me my nvidia card or allow me to get my old launcher icons back

Comment: Maybe you confused apt by your attempts. In my case installing Ubuntu desktop 13.04 from scratch, the additional drivers showed up. Note that during installation I was asked if I agreed to use none open source programs and I checked yes. Maybe this is what is missing for you. I have this line active in my apt sources.list : deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main. Maybe it's there. partner was not active, so it's not there.

Answer (score 0):

If Nvidia drivers disappeared from "additional drivers" list, then you should try to install "nvidia-common"

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-common`

Comment: I did this, Unity didn't crash again.. but still nothing in the additional drivers tab, nor does it show up in the About System > Graphics